# Selenium Python - Internet Explorer - Problem

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new on Selenium and I'm trying to do a task using Internet Explorer (I'm using Python 3.8)

In order to uderstand the commands of Selenium, I tried to run the simple code below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver=webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\Users\\usuario\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com.br/")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)


driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Ronaldinho Gaucho")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


driver.maximize_window()
driver.refresh()
```

The page opens, however, nothing is typed on the search bar on Google website, I have seen this code in a Youtube video and it has worked well, but when I try on my computer, it does not works (it does not raise any error on my terminal)

Anyone can help?, what I should been looking for?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the problem occur only for IE?

Comment: Try `driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER)` What is the output. Or `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: The problem is, for the real application I will do later, it requires internet explorer, that is the only reason I'm using this browser

Comment: I understand, but can you check if this code will work for Firefox or Chrome? It will help identify the problem. I don't have Windows at this moment.